# Terraform variable without interpolation

Tags: terraform

This seems like a simple question and maybe I'm misreading the documentation somewhere.  I am trying to set a variable with a string value, in my case it is a SAS token for an Azure blob, which I then want to pass in to a template deployment.  The issue that I am running into is that the string gets interpolated causing the token to be invalid.  I am unable to figure out how I can pass a variable and not have it be interpolated.

```
scripts_blob_sas_token = "${var.scripts_blob_sas_token}"
```

This is the string:

```
?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=O%2FurgY2Eu%2FZN3Ax1GSN58cNpc2DRMahLdB7lPqVifNc%3D&st=2017-06-13T17%3A17%3A45Z&se=2027-06-13T17%3A17%3A45Z&sp=r
```

When I reference the `${var.scripts_blob_sas_token}` variable it get interpolated to this:

```
?sv=2015-04-05\\u0026sr=c\\u0026sig=O%2FurgY2Eu%2FZN3Ax1GSN58cNpc2DRMahLdB7lPqVifNc%3D\\u0026st=2017-06-13T17%3A17%3A45Z
```

Is there a way to call a variable in Terraform and escape interpolation of the string?

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you passing the string into the variable? I've personally never had an issue with encoding on URLs in terraform. I wonder if that's happening before the string reaches Terraform. Or conversely, perhaps it something could be escaping the string in the resource provider or provisioner you are using, rather than in the interpolation engine. What resource or provisioner is that value being passed to? It might also help to know what version of terraform you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the variable into a file and read it into a string.

> file(path) - Reads the contents of a file into the string. **Variables in this file are not interpolated**. The contents of the file are read as-is. The path is interpreted relative to the working directory. Path variables can be used to reference paths relative to other base locations. For example, when using file() from inside a module, you generally want to make the path relative to the module base, like this: file("${path.module}/file").

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#file-path-